How can I use the onClick functionality of one component inside another component in React?
I am creating a whatsapp clone.
For showing profile picture, I have made a card component which is accessed from a top_bar component.
function Show_dp(prop){

    return(
        <div id="box">
            <div id="dp">
                <img src={prop.image}></img>
            </div>
            <div id="buttons">
                <div className="buttons_dp">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon className="ico" fontSize="1.5em" color="white"  icon={faMessage} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Show_dp;

The top_bar component is as follows:
function Top_bar(prop){

    const [dp, setdp] = useState(false);

    function toggle_dp(){
        setdp(!dp);
        console.log(dp);
    }

    return(
        <>
            <div id="bar_container">
                <div id="bar_left">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon fontSize="1.2em" color="#ebebeb"  icon={faArrowLeftLong} className="icon"/>
                    {/* <FontAwesomeIcon fontSize="1.5em" color="#ebebeb"  icon={faUserCircle} className="icon"/> */}
                    <div id="profile_picture" onClick={toggle_dp}>
                        <img src={prop.image}></img>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="bar_middle">{prop.name}</div>
                <div id="bar_right">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon fontSize="1.1em" color="#ebebeb"  icon={faVideoCamera} className="icon"/>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon fontSize="1.1em" color="#ebebeb"  icon={faPhone} className="icon"/>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon fontSize="1.1em" color="#ebebeb"  icon={faCog} className="icon"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="dp_card" style={{display: dp? "flex": "none"}}>
                <Show_dp image = {profile_picture} />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Top_bar;

In this, top_bar component, whenever I will click on the profile_picture div, it will show the dp_card component.
Now, when the dp_card component is showing, I want to make the buttons_dp buttons of the dp_card do something inside the top_bar component (i.e. hide the dp_card onClick).
So, I want to access the onClick button of a Show_dp component from the Top_bar component.
How can I do the same? Please help me learn a new thing!

In the above image (showing the dp_card component), I want to access the message button (left_most) which will help remove the dp_card (i.e. set display of dp_card to "none").
I am facing trouble with using a onClick button of one component inside another component.

In the Top_bar component, send dp and setdp method along with profile_picture, this will allow you to use the setdp function in the Show_dp component:
Make changes in Top_bar here:


<div id="dp_card" style={{display: dp? "flex": "none"}}>
      <Show_dp image = {profile_picture} isDpVisible={dp} setDp={setdp} />
</div>



You can do something like this in Show_dp component:


function Show_dp(prop){

    function handleClick(){
        prop.setDp(false);
        console.log(prop.dp);
    }

    return(
        <div id="box" style={{display: prop.isDpVisible ? "flex" : "none"}}>
            <div id="dp">
                <img src={prop.image}></img>
            </div>
            <div id="buttons">
                <div className="buttons_dp" onClick={handleClick}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon className="ico" fontSize="1.5em" color="white"  icon={faMessage} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Show_dp;



